# Angular JS Working with JSON Data

Tags: json, angularjs, google-visualization

I am using https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart for Data Visualization.

I need to get data from JSON file.

Below is the snippet which was responsible for data display on html page:

```
$scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};
```

I changed it to:

```
    $scope.chartObject.data = function(){
    $http.get('data.json').always(function(response) {
    return response.data;
    });
    }
```

And my console throws following error :

```
Object {id: "google-visualization-errors-0", message: "Table has no columns.", detailedMessage: "", options: Object}
```

My `data.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

**NOTE:** FilePath is not a problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong about the way that you set the $http request response to your $scope object. Change it to:

```
$scope.chartObject.data = {} 

$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.chartObject.data = response.data;
});
```

This is because you cannot directly set a Promise (the object that $http.get returns) to a object in your scope, because it is async.

Comment: This worked fine, I needed to pass " $http" as parameter in my controller. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to this

$scope.chartObject = {};

```
     $scope.chartObject.data = {} 

$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.chartObject.data = response.data;
});
```

Comment: pass $http in your controller parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Also you will need add $http dependency on the controller.

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data){
return data;
}).error(function(data){
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you use factory Then consume it from anywhere.

**Service**

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http){
    var getData = function(){
         return $http.get('data.json');
    }
    return {
        getData: getData
    }               
});
```

Before using it don't forget to add dependency of service inside your controller.

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.chartObject = {}; //do this if chartObject is not initialized
dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.chartObject.data = response.data;
});
```

Hope better code will work for you.Thanks.